# Captivate playback control skin in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe-captivate

How can I create and control Captivate Playback Skin in Flash with my custom layout and script?

Comment: You need to add more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clicking Project > Skin > Borders tab and DE-selecting the "Show Borders" check box, remove the controls as well. Then load/import the swf and you can control it by setting the command variable (rdcmndPause, rdcmndResume, rdcmndRewindAndStop, rdcmndRewindAndPlay, rdcmndNextSlide, rdcmndPrevious, rdcmndInfo, rdcmndExit) to 1.

myVideoLoader.rdcmdRewindAndStop = 1